# How to access Maven resources directory from java code?

Tags: java, maven, freemarker

I am trying to access a file (hello.ftl) which is located in the resources folder of a maven project.

This is the class that tries to access the directory :

HelloFreemarker.java

```
package mypackage.main;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class HelloFreemarker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());

        cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("."));

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("name", "World");

        Template template = cfg.getTemplate("hello.ftl");
        template.process(model, new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    }
}
```

The error I get in the console is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "hello.ftl" not found.
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:742)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:665)
    at mypackage.main.HelloFreemarker.main(HelloFreemarker.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried using `HelloFreemarker.class.getResource("hello.ftl");` or `HelloFreemarker.class.getResource("/hello.ftl");`? This assumes that the `Configuration#getTemplate` accepts a `URL`

Comment: To get the path of a file in the classpath you have to write  getClass().getResource("/hello.ftl").getPath()

Comment: Thank guys, the HelloFreemarket.class.getResource("../..").getPath() line gave me the correct String variable to use as argument with new File() object creation.

Comment: Post your solution as a formal answer to help others. Good job!

Comment: Ok!I'll post the solution right away!

Answer (score 1):

This is the HelloFreemarker class after some code changes suggested by the guys that added the comments :

```
package mypackage.main;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class HelloFreemarker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());

        String path = HelloFreemarker.class.getResource("../..").getPath();

        cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(path));

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("name", "World");

        Template template = cfg.getTemplate("hello.ftl");
        template.process(model, new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    }
}
```

The two directory up commands are necessary to get from the directory of the compiled class to the directory where the file resides(target/classes).

Comment: FreeMarker doesn't need a `File` to load templates, it can load "resources" directly. See `cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading`.